# Codeigniter sending multiple email bbc not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, bcc

I've sent an email with the Codeigniter (2.1.4) Email library, but the function send return true while I'm not getting the email ?!
Here is the code : http://pastebin.com/rYdkr2VD.

```
$config = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'bcc_batch_mode' => true,
    'bcc_batch_size' => 200
);
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('xxxx@site.yyy', 'Site name');
$this->email->to('');
$this->email->bcc($emails); // array('wwww@site.yyy', 'zzzz@site.yyyy')
$this->email->subject($subject); // string
$this->email->message($content); // html content
if( !$this->email->send() ) {
    die('Error!');
}
```

But if I introduce an email with the function "to", the email is sent to it but not to the bcc emails.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include relevant(!) parts of code directly in your question.

Comment: does '$this->email->to($emails);' work?

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
'bcc_batch_mode' => true,
'bcc_batch_size' => 200
```

Add a value to

```
$this->email->to('');
```

like

```
$this->email->to('test@test.nl');"
```

else try adding them 1 by 1 like

```
$this->email->bcc('1email1@email.com');
$this->email->bcc('2email2@email.com');
```

Comment: I've tried, message arrives at the well to `$this->email->to`, but the problem is that the emails in `$this->email->bcc` not receive the message ?!